Slow Laravel Application
My client have a bought a laravel script from codecanyon in order to start development of a web platform and that script had already some of features implemented which we need.
The script bought is for admin panel and I am extending it to implement his custom features and also to build apis for web frontend (Next.js) and mobile (android & ios).
The problem I am facing is that the laravel script is extremely slow. In my local enviorment and also on server it tasks around 1.4-2 seconds per api request which should be no more than 100-200 ms atleast in local.
I did some digging and following are some interesting findings on the subject.

If i create a route and return 'hello world' from controller the time it takes to hit the controller i.e the first line inside the controller to be logged is 1.2-1.8 seconds
The time it takes to register service providers is also like 400ms
In the service provider registration process, I edited the vendor files of laravel and logged the time along with provider names and found out that there are many service providers which are not even in configs and are coming from packages

My problem is I do not know where to look. So if can come up with some steps to investigate further please let me know
~ I have also setup laravel debug bar played around with turning off dev enviroment and other basic things but to no avail.
Thank You
Edit::
I should have mentioned it my bad,
I am using windows, xampp enviroment
My coworker is using mac with some php env and have same issue
On server we have linux debian and have same issue there too
I installed laravel debug bar in my local but it just gave me 800 ms bootstrap time - but still I do not know why it took that much time

There are a ton of reasons why your code could be slow when loading any page. Laravel does come with some overheard, but 1.8 - 2 seconds for a "hello world" is egregious though... You can install something call "Laravel Debugbar" locally, and it'll potentially give you some information on what could be causing the long load times. Beyond that, there isn't much we can do, since we can't see your code...

Remove packages that you do not use. package discovery means that their service providers may run just because the packages are installed. To help debugging you can check the time it takes to hit the first line of a controller by doing microtime(true)-LARAVEL_START to get time since the request hit the PHP entry point.

Are you working in Windows docker environment? If so, it is known to have this issue.

I have edited the question to have more details - I'll check it iwth microtime and let you guys know.
Thanks for the help
